# How to select all rows from database and write in label, textbox or anywhere

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

```
SqlDataReader reader = null;
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::vaja15.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
cn.Open();

SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Uporabnik WHERE attacktype='melee' ", cn);

reader = sda.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    richTextBox1.Text = reader[4].ToString();
}

cn.Close();
```

How can I select every row that is in the database like melee?

Comment: You're already selecting every row, but you're overwriting the text box each time, so you're only _displaying_ the last item.

Comment: Your current code doesn't work? What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you use `.Text` on the RichTextBox, you can store *only one value* - therefore, each subsequent value overwrites the previous one. You need to put your data into a control that can handle multiple values - a listbox, a grid - something of that sort

Comment: it writes the last row everytime not all

Comment: i tried it now with listbox but it doesnt write anything

Comment: Try `richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text == null ? reader[4].ToString() : richTextBox1.Text+ reader[4].ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to dynamically add new TextBox or Label for each iteration of the while loop if you want this to work:

```
while (reader.Read())
{

    TextBox dynamicTextbox = new TextBox();
    Panel1.Controls.Add(dynamicTextbox );
    dynamicTextbox.Text = reader[4].ToString();
}
```

Note I am assuming you are using a Panel to group the textboxes together.

Comment: I have extended the code example. Does it now solve your problem ?

Comment: I corrected the syntax. dynamicTextbox  was using inconsistent capitalisation.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: change: dynamicTextbox.Text = reader[4].ToString
 to:  dynamicTextbox.Text = reader[4].ToString();

Comment: Yes, sorry I think I lost some characters when copying and pasting from your post.

Comment: now its working but still writing down only 1 from database not all rows idk